# Big O notation complexity for binary multiplcation

Tags: big-o

What is the Big O notation for the following operations:

A = 1*(1 0 1 0) + 0*(0 1 0 1)

---

Thank you OlivierLi. So, please what about this : A = 1*(0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0) + 0*(1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1) + 1 * (1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0) + 0 * (1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0). It is also O(1). As you see it is like one binary bit multiplied by 8 binary bits four times. If it is also O (1), please and kindly, How can I prove that. Thank you with best regards.

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you want to know. Like this it doesn't make sense to me. The operation will always take exactly the same time.

Comment: Why is this tagged Matlab?

Comment: If I do this in MATLAB , What is the Big O fir that operation ?

Comment: @ Dan, Nabla, MikDiet, John Kugelman, SK9. My question is, What is the Big O for: A = 1*(0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0) + 0*(1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1) + 1 * (1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0) + 0 * (1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is O(1).

It doesn't depend on any input at all and is always constant.

Comment: So, please what about this :

Comment: Thank you OlivierLi. So, please what about this : A = 1*(0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0) + 0*(1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1) + 1 * (1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0) + 0 * (1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0). It is also O(1). As you see it is like one binary bit multiplied by 8 binary bits four times. If it is also O (1), please and kindly, How can I prove that. Thank you with best regards.

Comment: The operation is still completely independent from the input( there is none) so it is still O(1).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities

Comment: If you feel this answered your question, please mark it as resolved using the check mark on the left.

Comment: Sorry for any annoyance, I am new about that subject (i.e., Big O notation complexity). If we consider that operation like binary multiplication between array (1*4) with matrix (4*8), as you know we optian as the output array (1*8). Also, it is O(1) ? When we say it is O(n) ? Thank you so much

Comment: This is a new question. If you would like it answered please mark this one as answered and post it as a new question.

Comment: I think the complexity here NOT O(1), it is O(7) because we have 4 multiplication operations and 3 addition operations.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, whether we assume the count of bits as a variable or as a constant.

Constant count of bits: the complexity is O(1), because the complexity is the same for all possible input numbers.

Variable count of bits: for each bit of first number you add the shifted second number. Considering that addition with arbitrary long numbers may have complexity O(N), the final complexity is O(N^2), where N is the count of bits.

Comment: @user3319291: I wasn't asking this question _If we say the count of bits is constant always ? The Big O is O(1)._, please add a comment instead, if you want... And also I don't understand voters, who voted for the approval of this change...

Comment: Sorry, If we say that the count of bits is  always constant  and we have four bits multiplied by eight bits. What is the O in this case ?

Comment: @Sam V-X's answer clearly states the result for this case.

Comment: I think the complexity here NOT O(1), it is O(7) because we have 4 multiplication operations and 3 addition operations.